# Using xPath to select all children of specific tag

Tags: php, xpath

I want to get all paragraph tags of div, but the script just fetch first paragraph tag.

Page is something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id="body">
          <p dir="ltr">parageraph one.</p>
          <p dir="ltr">parageraph two.</p>
          <p dir="ltr">parageraph three.</p>
          <p dir="ltr">parageraph three.</p>
          <span>span tag.</span>
        </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

My script is :

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$dom_obj = new DOMDocument();
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8');
$dom_obj->loadHtml($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom_obj);
$response = $xpath->query('//div[@id="body"]/p');
```

Why does it fetch only first paragraph tag?!

---

I found the problem :), The script works well,I should fetch the response like this:

```
$response = $xpath->query('//div[@id="body"]/p');
foreach ($response as $entry) {
    echo $entry->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: It fetches 4 tags: https://3v4l.org/GZBAU

Comment: yes you are right, i found my problem